# Один большой файл или много мелких

Tags: c++, файлы

Нужно записывать последние сообщения пользователей, если до этого было уже записано от него сообщение - перезаписать.

Мои варианты:

1. Один большой текстовый файл, который будет открываться при старте программы, в котором будут десятки тысяч строк текста, в которых постоянно нужно находить пользователя по его имени и перезаписывать его сообщение;
2. Создать отдельный файл под каждого пользователя, открывать их при надобности, и закрывать, допустим, после 5 минут бездействия.

Какая реализация более рациональна? А может есть идея получше?
Условное количество пользователей - 10.000, количество сообщений в минуту > 100

Comment: может все таки взять какую нибудь БД, с ними оно как то удобнее ...

Comment: Очевидный вариант — база данных.

Answer (score 2):

Если уж нельзя с базой данных, и обязателен файл (может, просто в памяти держать?) - то я бы сделал файл с фиксированным размером записи, чтоб точно хватало для этого сообщения, типа

```
struct {
    char user[N];
    char msg[M];
}
```

При открытии файла создавал бы в памяти список "пользователь - позиция в файле" (тот же `map`) и перезаписывал бы нужное место, которое бы очень быстро находил без поиска в самом файле. При добавлении пользователя - соответственно расширял бы файл.

Текстовый формат для такого - проще застрелиться - все время переписывать файл до конца...

Но все же подумайте - может, лучше держать в памяти, и сбрасывать в файл только время от времени? А то у вас будет сплошное пиление диска...